# Confusion on metric determinant derivative

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, differentiation, linear-algebra

Maybe it is a stupid confusion. I need to compute the derivative of the metric determinant with respect to the metric itself, i.e., $\partial g/\partial g_{\mu\nu}$, but I have an indices confusion in the final obtention of this expression. Recall the [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula) $\det e^{B}=e^{tr B}$, where $B$ is a matrix. Then, if $e^B=A$, we can write
\begin{align}
\det A=e^{tr \ln A}.
\end{align}
Applying logarithms to both sides, we have
\begin{align}
\ln \det A=tr \ln A.
\end{align}
Now, applying the partial derivative with respect to matrix $A$, we arrive to
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\det A}\frac{\partial \det A}{\partial A}=tr\left(A^{-1}\right).
\end{align}
I think that at this point, everything is ok. Now, if we set $A_{ \mu \nu}=g_{ \mu \nu}$, where $g_{\mu\nu}$ is the metric of a certain spacetime, then we obtain
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}=tr(g^{\mu\nu}),
\end{align}
or, using the fact that the trace of the inverse matrix can be written in components as $tr(g^{\mu\nu})=g_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu}$ (it is convenient for me to write the trace in components),
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial g}{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}=g g_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu}.
\end{align}
On the left-hand side, we have $\frac{\partial g}{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}$, a tensor that depends on two contravariant indices, while on the right-hand side, we have no indices. I am confused. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally I think it's clearer when expressed in terms of variations (the first order variation is always the derivative, but for matrices the derivative can easily be missunderstood): let $g^{\mu\nu} \to g^{\mu\nu} + \delta g^{\mu\nu}$. Now use $\ln \mathrm{det}\,M = \mathrm{tr}\ln M$ and vary
\begin{align*}
\ln\det(g + \delta g) = \ln (\det(g) + \delta \det(g) + \mathcal{O}(\delta^2)) = \ln \det(g) + \frac{1}{\det(g)}\delta \det(g) + \mathcal{O}(\delta^2)
\end{align*}
and the RHS
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{tr}\ln(g + \delta g) = \mathrm{tr}\left[\ln(g) + \ln(1 + g^{-1}\delta g)\right] = \mathrm{tr}\ln(g) + \mathrm{tr}\left[g^{-1}\delta g + \mathcal{O}(\delta^2)\right]
\end{align*}
Comparing the terms at $\mathcal{O}(\delta)$ you find
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\det(g)}\delta \det(g) = \mathrm{tr}(g^{-1}\delta g)
\end{align*}
So for the differential of the determinant you get
\begin{align*}
\delta \det(g) = \det(g)\mathrm{tr}\left(g^{\mu\nu}\delta g_{\nu\sigma}\right) = \det(g) g^{\mu\nu}\delta g_{\nu\mu}
\end{align*}
Now you can basically read of the derivative
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial \det(g)}{\partial g_{\mu\nu}} = \frac{\delta \det(g)}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}} = \det(g) g^{\mu\nu}
\end{align*}

From here you can also find the derivative wrt. the inverse metric easily: to find the variation of the metric note that
\begin{align*}
\delta^{\alpha}_\beta = g^{\alpha\lambda}g_{\lambda\beta} \to g^{\alpha\lambda}g_{\lambda\beta} + g^{\alpha\lambda}\delta g_{\lambda \beta} + \delta g^{\alpha\lambda} g_{\lambda\beta} + \mathcal{O}(\delta g^2)
\end{align*}
so we require that
\begin{align*}
0 &= g^{\alpha\lambda}\delta g_{\lambda\beta} + \delta g^{\alpha\lambda}g_{\lambda\beta} \\
g_{\gamma\alpha}g^{\alpha\lambda} \delta g_{\lambda\beta} &= - g_{\gamma\alpha} g_{\lambda\beta}\delta g^{\alpha\lambda} \\
\delta g_{\gamma\beta} &= - g_{\gamma\alpha} g_{\lambda\beta} \delta g^{\alpha\lambda}
\end{align*}
Now just plug this into the differential of the determinant to get
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial \det(g)}{\partial g^{\mu\nu}} &= \frac{\delta \det(g)}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}} = \frac{1}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}} \det(g) g^{\alpha\beta}(-g_{\alpha\gamma}g_{\beta\delta} \delta g^{\gamma\delta}) = - \det(g) g_{\mu\nu}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 9):

We have
$$
\ln \det A = \text{Tr} \ln A
$$
When you take a derivative, we find
$$
\frac{1}{\det A} \frac{\partial \det A}{ \partial A_{ij} } = \frac{\partial }{ \partial A_{ij} } \text{Tr} \ln A = (A^{-1})^{ij} 
$$
Then,
$$
\frac{ \partial g}{ \partial g_{\mu\nu}} = g g^{\mu\nu} 
$$

Comment: It is not clear to me the identity 
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial A_{ij}}\mathrm{tr} \ln A=(A^{-1})^{ij}.
\end{align}

Comment: @SoniaLlambias Choose an eigenbasis of $A$ then $\operatorname{tr}\ln A=\sum_k \ln \lambda_{k}$. In this basis the matrix is diagonal with $\lambda_k = A_{kk}$, so $$\operatorname{tr}\ln A=\sum_k \ln A_{kk}.$$
It follows that
$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial A_{ij}}\operatorname{tr}\ln A = \sum_k \dfrac{1}{A_{kk}}\dfrac{\partial A_{kk}}{\partial A_{ij}}=\sum_k \dfrac{1}{A_{kk}} \delta_{ik}\delta_{kj} = \dfrac{1}{A_{ii}}\delta_{ij}.$$
In this basis we also have $(A^{-1})^{ij}= \frac{1}{A_{ii}}\delta_{ij}$, so the RHS is really $(A^{-1})^{ij}$ as we wanted to show.