Are the quantity $\frac{\delta \sqrt{-g}}{\delta g_{\mu \nu}}$, $\frac{\delta \sqrt{-g}}{\delta g^{\mu \nu}} $ are computable?
From $\delta \sqrt{-g} = -\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-g} g_{\alpha \beta}\delta  g^{\alpha \beta} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-g} g^{\alpha \beta} \delta g_{\alpha \beta}$, can we compute
\begin{align}
&\frac{\delta \sqrt{-g}}{\delta g_{\mu \nu}} =?  \\
&\frac{\delta \sqrt{-g}}{\delta g^{\mu \nu}} =?  
\end{align}
I know that $\sqrt{-g}$ is a tensor density. It seems if $\delta g_{\alpha \beta}$ is invertible there might be some manipulation, but $g^{\alpha \beta} \delta g_{\alpha \beta}$ seems like scalar, so it is quite tricky to factorized then properly.
Usually when we define energy momentum tensor
\begin{align}
&\delta S_m = -\frac{1}{2} \int d^d x \sqrt{-g} T^{\mu \nu} \delta g_{\mu \nu} \\
& \Rightarrow \quad T^{\mu \nu} = -\frac{2}{\sqrt{-g}} \frac{\delta S_m}{\delta g_{\mu \nu}}
\end{align}
In this perspective I think I can write
\begin{align}
&\frac{\delta \sqrt{-g}}{\delta g_{\mu \nu}} = - \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-g} g^{\mu \nu}   \\
&\frac{\delta \sqrt{-g}}{\delta g^{\mu \nu}} = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-g} g_{\mu \nu}
\end{align}
But I am not sure wheter my process is well-defined.

Jacobi's formula might be of interest for you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula

see e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/772725
